# Android application has stopped, can't understand error log

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm making a simple game that first asks for a difficulty in the main activity.  It calls a new activity that asks for a game mode.  That calls a new activity for the actual game which just tells the user to tap the screen when the color changes, and measures their reaction time. As soon as I run it, it tells me "Unfortunately, the application has stopped" and there are a lot of errors.  I've seen nearly the exact same set of errors in other questions, but none of the answers has applied to me. Any suggestions?  I'm sorry if this question seems vague, I have no idea how to handle this. The following is the Android Manifest, the code for the three activities, and the error log:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.dabaam.battlereaction"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.dabaam.battlereaction.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.dabaam.battlereaction.GameType">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.dabaam.battlereaction.Game">
    </activity>

</application>
```

Activity 1:

```
package com.dabaam.battlereaction;

import android.app.Activity;  
import android.content.Intent;  
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.widget.Button;  
import android.view.View;  

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button ezbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ezbtn);
Button medbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.medbtn);
Button hardbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hardbtn);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ezbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            askDifficulty("EASY");
        }
    });

    medbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            askDifficulty("MEDIUM");
        }
    });

    hardbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            askDifficulty("HARD");
        }
    });
}

private void askDifficulty(String whichDiff){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GameType.class);
    intent.putExtra(GameType.difficulty, whichDiff);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Activity 2:

```
package com.dabaam.battlereaction;

import android.app.Activity;  
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.view.View;  
import android.widget.Button;  
import android.content.Intent;  

public class GameType extends Activity{
public static String difficulty = "difficulty";

public static final String EASY = "EASY";
public static final String MEDIUM = "MEDIUM";
public static final String HARD = "HARD";

Button visbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.vis_btn);
Button tactbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tact_btn);
Button audbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.aud_btn);

public void onCreate(Bundle b){
    super.onCreate(b);
    setContentView(R.layout.type_layout);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    //if( extras.getString(difficulty).equals(EASY) ){
        // Start EASY game
    difficulty = extras.getString(difficulty);

    visbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            launchGame(difficulty,"VISUAL");
        }
    });

    tactbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            launchGame(difficulty,"TACTILE");
        }
    });

    audbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            launchGame(difficulty,"AUDITORY");
        }
    });

}

private void launchGame(String whichDiff, String whichMode){
    Intent intent = new Intent(GameType.this, Game.class);
    intent.putExtra(Game.difficulty, whichDiff);
    intent.putExtra(Game.mode, whichMode);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Activity 3:

```
package com.dabaam.battlereaction;

import java.util.Random;  
import java.util.Timer;  
import java.util.TimerTask;  

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;  
import android.app.Activity;  
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.view.MotionEvent;  
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;  
import android.view.View;  
import android.widget.LinearLayout;  
import android.widget.TextView;  

public class Game extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{
LinearLayout glayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.gameLayout);
public static final String difficulty = "difficulty";
public static final String mode = "mode";
public Random r = new Random();
int after = r.nextInt(10000 - 2000) + 2000;
public long time1 = 0;
public long time2 = 0;
public long elapsed = 1212121; //1212121 by default for debugging
public String ms_score = "1212121"; //1212121 by default

public void onCreate(Bundle b){
    super.onCreate(b);
    setContentView(R.layout.game_layout);
    new Timer().schedule(change(), after);
}
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    time2= System.nanoTime();
    elapsed = (time2-time1)/1000000;

    TextView score = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    ms_score = getString(R.string.score, elapsed);
    score.setText(ms_score);
    glayout.addView(score);

    return false;
}

@SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor") public TimerTask change() {
    glayout.setBackgroundColor(R.color.Blue);
    time1= System.nanoTime();
    return null;
}       
}
```

Error log:

```
07-01 17:01:43.490: E/AndroidRuntime(20563): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-01 17:01:43.490: E/AndroidRuntime(20563): Process: com.dabaam.battlereaction, PID: 20563
07-01 17:01:43.490: E/AndroidRuntime(20563): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.dabaam.battlereaction/com.dabaam.battlereaction.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-01 17:01:43.490: E/AndroidRuntime(20563):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2514)
07-01 17:01:43.490: E/AndroidRuntime(20563):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2653)
07-01 17:01:43.490: E/AndroidRuntime(20563):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
07-01 17:01:43.490: E/AndroidRuntime(20563):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
07-01 17:01:43.490: E/AndroidRuntime(20563):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-01 17:01:43.490: E/AndroidRuntime(20563):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
07-01 17:01:43.490: E/AndroidRuntime(20563):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
07-01 17:01:43.490: E/AndroidRuntime(20563):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-01 17:01:43.490: E/AndroidRuntime(20563):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-01 17:01:43.490: E/AndroidRuntime(20563):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1069)
07-01 17:01:43.490: E/AndroidRuntime(20563):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:885)
07-01 17:01:43.490: E/AndroidRuntime(20563):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-01 17:01:43.490: E/AndroidRuntime(20563): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-01 17:01:43.490: E/AndroidRuntime(20563):    at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1952)
07-01 17:01:43.490: E/AndroidRuntime(20563):    at com.dabaam.battlereaction.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:11)
07-01 17:01:43.490: E/AndroidRuntime(20563):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
07-01 17:01:43.490: E/AndroidRuntime(20563):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
07-01 17:01:43.490: E/AndroidRuntime(20563):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1079)
07-01 17:01:43.490: E/AndroidRuntime(20563):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2505)
07-01 17:01:43.490: E/AndroidRuntime(20563):    ... 11 more
07-01 17:01:47.684: D/Process(20563): killProcess, pid=20563
07-01 17:01:47.684: D/Process(20563): com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException:131 java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:693 java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:690
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move

```
Button ezbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ezbtn);
Button medbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.medbtn);
Button hardbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hardbtn);
```

under

```
setContentView(R.layout.type_layout);
```

Your buttons are not created when you try to find them using `findViewById()`, therefore you get a NullPointerException.

After declaring your layout, they are created.

Answer (score 1):

Your application crashes because of this line:

```
LinearLayout glayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.gameLayout);
```

The crash occurs because you **cannot find** a `View` **before the contentView has been set**, which happens in the `onCreate(...)` method of your `Activity`.

Move the initialization of "glayout" below the `setContentView(...)` call.

In addition to that, i'd go with [yygyt's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/655987/yygyt) suggestion.

Comment: Thank you, this allowed the app to run through the first two activities, but still crashes on the third. Should glayout be initialized within the onCreate method? Or between it and the onTouch method? Because it needs to be used in both onTouch and change() methods.

Comment: Make it a member variable. But initialize it after setContentView(...) is called.